# DoEvents() in IronPython WPF application

Tags: ironpython

I'm looking for an equivalent of Application.DoEvents for an IronPython WPF application. I've found a few examples in C#, but I've had no luck translating them to IronPython, eg:

```html
private void DoEvents()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                  new Action(delegate { }));
        }
```

I already know it would be more elegant to write a properly multi-threaded application, but I'm just after a quick hack for some disposable code.

Many thanks,

900RK

Comment: What is your aim? The code you posted just invoke some thing but does nothing really at all. Do you look for something like `UpdateLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from System.Windows.Forms.Application import DoEvents
....
DoEvents()
```